# Saving Structure leads to error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Tags: crash, save, structure, workspace

I have two different structures (DATA and orient). They both are build up like this: DATA.S(1).M(1).A(1).var1 etc...

When I want to save them with the following lines:

```
text='data1';

filename=strcat('save/',text,'.mat');

save(filename, 'DATA', 'orient');
```

I get the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." for the save line.

When I stop the Programm before the line and try to save it manually over the Workspace matlab is crashing but using all the processing power.

I'm using MAtlab R2014a an the structs are between 2000-4000Bytes.

I hope anyone has a idea what it could be about. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I simply used the following code(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39721-save-mat-files-more-quickly/content/savefast.m) from Tim Holy. Now it works without any problems. Thanks Tim Holy!!! :)